# How to find the direction of an “L” shape in a image

Tags: pyqgis, algorithm, extents

I  need to find the moving direction of a vehicle by its extracted point cloud, and I have converted the point cloud to the following image.

[image]
[image]
[image]

As the target vehicle could be moving straight or turning and the image is sometimes clear and sometimes fuzzy, I find it's difficult to match the "L" shape using template matching.

I also try to use RANSAC to fit the linear, but it has two sides and RANSAC does not work well. What I need to do is using an oriented bounding box to represent the vehicle.

If I could have the yaw angle of the "L" shape, it's very easy to recover it to an oriented bounding box. So could anyone give me some suggestions?

PS: I have asked this question at stackoverflow, but nothing helps. So forgive me again post this question here.
PS: The function cv::minAreaRect could offer a basic result, but it sometimes fit the "L" shape in a wrong direction.

[image]

Comment: What's your software do you use ?

Comment: Actually, I need some algorithm hits to implement this by code. So the software does not really matter.

Comment: Maybe convert into polyline, simplify, split by line vertices and then calculate direction of the longest polyline

Comment: Minimum spanning tree and find 2 points most far away from each other? Simplify line after that...

Answer (score 1):

My approach uses **GDAL/PyQGIS** code and it was run with a point raster layer where points have a "L" shape trajectory (see next image) and a gray scale to represent point order (zeros are corresponding to non trajectory).

[image]

So, following code read raster data and takes non zero values to build **QgsPoints** with its respective order indexes. Afterward, **QgsPoints** are used to build an oriented bounding box by using 'qgis:orientedminimumboundingbox' tool of Python QGIS proccesing.

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np 
import processing

raster_path = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/trajectory_L_shape.tif'

dataset = gdal.Open(raster_path)
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

data = band.ReadAsArray()

nonzero = zip(data.nonzero()[0], data.nonzero()[1])

values = [ data[element[0], element[1]] for element in nonzero ]

points_idx = [ [QgsPoint(geotransform[0] + geotransform[1]/2 + indices[1]*geotransform[1],
               geotransform[3] + geotransform[5]/2 + indices[0]*geotransform[5]), values[i]]
               for i, indices in enumerate(nonzero) ]

points_idx.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) #to sort by second column

wkt = dataset.GetProjection()

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(wkt)
epsg = srs.GetAttrValue("AUTHORITY", 1)

uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + epsg + "&field=id:integer&field=order:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'point',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(points_idx)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i,int(points_idx[i][1])])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(points_idx[i][0]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)

processing.runandload('qgis:orientedminimumboundingbox',
                      mem_layer,
                      False,
                      None)
```

After running the code at Python Console of QGIS I got:

[image]

where it can be observed point layer produced (where order of each point it coincides with id ascending) and oriented bounding box for "L" shape trajectory.